# Java Stream: changing the value of a property without calling a function

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I would like to know if it is possible to change the value of a property without calling a function, something like:

```
return findAll().stream()       
                .map(cps -> cps.setFavorited(true))
                .distinct()
                .collect(toList());
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your example isn't very clear to me. Could you please clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: unless that `setFavorited` returns `this`, that would not even compile...

Comment: On a different note, setters are also functions. That's why what Eugene pointed out holds true since in your case the return type of the setter matters(no more void). What did you mean without calling a function?

Comment: In general, you should not modify any objects in any way in streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, your stream solution would be something like:

```
return findAll().stream()       
                .map(cps -> {cps.setFavorited(true); return cps;})
                .distinct()
                .collect(toList());
```

Or your `setFavorited` could return `this`, thus allow chaining:

```
 public <Whatever> setFavorited(boolean flag){
     this.favorited = flag;
     return this;
 }
```

But you have to be very careful with these kind of things, since all you care about is `distinct` (that relies on *at least* `equals`). A stream implementation might detect that your `equals` could be based on some other properties besides `favorited`, thus it might, at least theoretically skip that `map`, entirely. This is probably far fetched, but in `java-9` this, for example, is an optimization:

```
Stream.of(1,2,3)
      .map(x -> x + 1)
      .count();
```

Since all you care about is `count`, `map` is skipped.